# Convolutional Neural Network that takes as input an RGB image and outputs a 10 element vector per pixel

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a Keras implementation of a CNN, specifically a UNet, which I train by providing as input a 256x256x3 (RGB) retina image and an accompanying image mask of the same size:

[image]
[image]

The mask is my ground truth. Each pixel in the mask is one of 10 unique colours (white, black, blue etc) which maps to the location of one of 10 biological layers in the original retina image.

The UNet output is a 256x256x3 image where each pixel should be the same colour value as the corresponding colour in the image mask. What I want the output to be, however, is a 256x256x10 array where each pixel holds the probability (0.0 to 1.0) of one of the 10 colours occupying that position at that pixel.

Here is the code of my Unet:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONV 2D BLOCK
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def conv2d_block(input_tensor, n_filters, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = True):
    """Function to add 2 convolutional layers with the parameters passed to it"""

    # first layer
    x = Conv2D(filters = n_filters, kernel_size = kernel_size, data_format="channels_last", \
              kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding = 'same')(input_tensor)

    if batchnorm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = Activation('relu')(x)

    # second layer
    x = Conv2D(filters = n_filters, kernel_size = kernel_size, data_format="channels_last", \
              kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding = 'same')(input_tensor)

    if batchnorm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = Activation('relu')(x)

    return x

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# GET THE U-NET ARCHITECTURE 
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def get_unet(input_img, n_filters = 16, dropout = 0.1, batchnorm = True):

    # Contracting Path (256 x 256 x 3)
    c1 = conv2d_block(input_img, n_filters * 1, kernel_size = (3, 3), batchnorm = batchnorm)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)
    p1 = Dropout(dropout)(p1)

    c2 = conv2d_block(p1, n_filters * 2, kernel_size = (3, 3), batchnorm = batchnorm)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)
    p2 = Dropout(dropout)(p2)

    c3 = conv2d_block(p2, n_filters * 4, kernel_size = (3, 3), batchnorm = batchnorm)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)
    p3 = Dropout(dropout)(p3)

    c4 = conv2d_block(p3, n_filters * 8, kernel_size = (3, 3), batchnorm = batchnorm)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c4)
    p4 = Dropout(dropout)(p4)

    c5 = conv2d_block(p4, n_filters = n_filters * 16, kernel_size = (3, 3), batchnorm = batchnorm)

    # Expansive Path
    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 8, 3, strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    u6 = Dropout(dropout)(u6)
    c6 = conv2d_block(u6, n_filters * 8, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)

    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 4, 3, strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    u7 = Dropout(dropout)(u7)
    c7 = conv2d_block(u7, n_filters * 4, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)

    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 2, 3, strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    u8 = Dropout(dropout)(u8)
    c8 = conv2d_block(u8, n_filters * 2, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)

    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 1, 3, strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(c8)    
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1])
    u9 = Dropout(dropout)(u9)
    c9 = conv2d_block(u9, n_filters * 1, kernel_size = 3, batchnorm = batchnorm)

    outputs = Conv2D(3, 1, activation='sigmoid')(c9)    

    model = Model(inputs=[input_img], outputs=[outputs])
    return model
```

My question is how can I alter the design of the network so that it takes the same inputs but produces a 256x256x10 prediction for each pixel of the corresponding input image and mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
outputs = Conv2D(10, 1, activation='softmax')(c9)
```

`outputs` is a tensor with shape `[?,256,256,10]` and softmax activation is taken along the last axis `(axis=-1)`.

Comment: Would I not need to do anything else with the input mask? How would my model know that a colour in the input mask (256x256x3) maps to a specific entry in the output (256x256x10)?

Comment: Thats preprocessing. You have to convert your input mask into a 256x256x10 tensor (one hot vectors for each pixel). You have to perform something like `keras.utils.to_categorical`.

Comment: So my image stays as a 256x256x3 but its corresponding mask becomes a 256x256x10 and the output is 256x256x10?

Comment: That's right. Each color will be one class and you have 10 different colors.